# Enable scrolling on a single div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, html

I have a layout that looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    stuff here
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="master">
      <div id="toolbar">
        <input type="text" id="foo">
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        a whole bunch of content in here
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

'#master' is a container for a jquery UI dialog. I'd like the contents of the '#content' div to be scrollable but for '#toolbar' to NOT be scrollable. Is this doable with jquery UI's dialog?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use css rules:

```
#content { overflow: auto; height: [desired height] }
```

Where you might need to use jQuery is if the modal has a dynamic height. In that case on `open` of the modal you could set the inner container height. Something like:

```
open: function(){
    var modalHeight = $('#master').height();
    $('#content').height(modalHeight - [footer and title]);
}
```

Comment: "open:" is a function to call when the dialog is opened?

Comment: Perfect! This is my first JS project so I am still learning. I appreciate the community's patience. :)

Comment: Hmm this works but if I resize up, the bottom of the dialog stretches but the #content height does not. If I resize smaller, a second scrollbar is added. I think I know why.. hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to give the `#content` div a set height and optionally a width, and set the CSS property `overflow: auto` on that div as well.  If the content exceeds the height, you'll get a scrollbar.

Comment: Additionally: refrain from setting a height on your dialog's constructor option.